# magento 2 :- Installation stuck at 75% on ubuntu OS

Tags: magento2, installation, development, ubuntu

Details of Console Log:-

```
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...

Required extensions check...

Enabling Maintenance Mode...

Installing deployment configuration...

Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':    
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_Directory':    
Module 'Magento_Amqp':    
Module 'Magento_Config':    
Module 'Magento_Theme':    
Module 'Magento_Backend':    
Module 'Magento_Variable':    
Module 'Magento_Eav':    
Module 'Magento_Search':    
Module 'Magento_Backup':    
Module 'Magento_Customer':    
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':    
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':    
Module 'Magento_Indexer':    
Module 'Magento_Cms':    
Module 'Magento_Security':    
Module 'Magento_GraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_Catalog':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':    
Module 'Magento_Rule':    
Module 'Magento_Msrp':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':    
Module 'Magento_StoreGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_Widget':
Module 'Magento_Quote':    
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':    
Module 'Magento_Payment':    
Module 'Magento_CmsGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':    
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_User':    
Module 'Magento_Sales':    
Module 'Magento_Checkout':    
Module 'Magento_EavGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':    
Module 'Magento_Contact':    
Module 'Magento_Cookie':    
Module 'Magento_Cron':    
Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':    
Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':    
Module 'Magento_Integration':    
Module 'Magento_CustomerGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_Deploy':    
Module 'Magento_Developer':    
Module 'Magento_Dhl':    
Module 'Magento_AsynchronousOperations':
Module 'Magento_DirectoryGraphQl':
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
Module 'Magento_CatalogGraphQl':
Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Module 'Magento_BundleGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedSearch':
Module 'Magento_Email':
Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':    
Module 'Magento_Fedex':    
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':    
Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':    
Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':    
Module 'Magento_Ui':    
Module 'Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_PageCache':    
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':    
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GroupedCatalogInventory':    
Module 'Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_AuthorizenetAcceptjs':    
Module 'Magento_InstantPurchase':    
Module 'Magento_Analytics':    
Module 'Magento_Inventory':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryBundleProduct':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalog':
Module 'Magento_InventorySales':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfiguration':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryElasticsearch':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryExportStockApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryIndexer':    
Module 'Magento_InventorySalesApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryCache':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryProductAlert':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryReservations':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryReservationCli':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryReservationsApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryExportStock':    
Module 'Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryShipping':
   Module 'Magento_Shipping':    
Module 'Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventorySourceSelection':    
Module 'Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi':    
Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':    
Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
  Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':    
Module 'Magento_MessageQueue':    
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct':    
Module 'Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct':    
Module 'Magento_Multishipping':    
Module 'Magento_MysqlMq':    
Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':    
Module 'Magento_Newsletter':    
Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':    
Module 'Magento_SalesRule':    
Module 'Magento_GraphQlCache':    
Module 'Magento_Vault':    
Module 'Magento_Paypal':    
Module 'Magento_Captcha':    
Module 'Magento_PaypalCaptcha':    
Module 'Magento_Persistent':    
Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':    
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':    
Module 'Magento_QuoteAnalytics':    
Module 'Magento_QuoteGraphQl':
Module 'Magento_ReleaseNotification':    
Module 'Magento_Reports':    
Module 'Magento_RequireJs':    
Module 'Magento_Review':   
Module 'Magento_ReviewAnalytics':    
Module 'Magento_Robots':    
Module 'Magento_Rss':    
Module 'Magento_Elasticsearch':    
Module 'MSP_ReCaptcha':    
Module 'Magento_SalesAnalytics':    
Module 'Magento_SalesGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':    
Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':    
Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':    
Module 'Magento_Elasticsearch6':    
Module 'Magento_CustomerAnalytics':    
Module 'Magento_SendFriend':    
Module 'Magento_SendFriendGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_Signifyd':    
Module 'Magento_Sitemap':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_SwaggerWebapi':

Module 'Magento_SwaggerWebapiAsync':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':

Module 'Magento_SwatchesGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Tax':

Module 'Magento_TaxGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_ThemeGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_Tinymce3':    
Module 'Magento_Translation':    
Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':    
Module 'Magento_Ups':    
Module 'Magento_SampleData':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_Usps':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':    
Module 'Magento_Braintree':    
Module 'Magento_VaultGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_Version':    
Module 'Magento_Swagger':    
Module 'Magento_WebapiAsync':    
Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':    
Module 'Magento_Weee':    
Module 'Magento_WeeeGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':    
Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Module 'Magento_WishlistAnalytics':    
Module 'Magento_WishlistGraphQl':    
Module 'Amazon_Core':    
Module 'Amazon_Login':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema...

Module 'Amazon_Payment': Upgrading schema...

Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema...    
Module 'Klarna_Core':  Installing schema... Upgrading schema...    
Module 'Klarna_Ordermanagement':    
Module 'Klarna_Kp':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema...    
Module 'Magento_PaypalReCaptcha':

Module 'MSP_TwoFactorAuth':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema...

Module 'Temando_Shipping':
Upgrading schema...

Module 'Vertex_Tax':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema...

Schema post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_Directory':    
Module 'Magento_Amqp':
Running schema recurring...    
Module 'Magento_Config':    
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Module 'Magento_Backend':    
Module 'Magento_Variable':    
Module 'Magento_Eav':    
Module 'Magento_Search':    
Module 'Magento_Backup':    
Module 'Magento_Customer':    
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':    
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':    
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running schema recurring...    
Module 'Magento_Cms':   
Module 'Magento_Security':    
Module 'Magento_GraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Running schema recurring...    
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_Rule':    
Module 'Magento_Msrp':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':    Running schema recurring...    
Module 'Magento_StoreGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_Widget':
Module 'Magento_Quote':    
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Running schema recurring...    
Module 'Magento_Payment':
Module 'Magento_CmsGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':    
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_User':    
Module 'Magento_Sales':    
Module 'Magento_Checkout':    
Module 'Magento_EavGraphQl':   
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_Contact':    
Module 'Magento_Cookie':    
Module 'Magento_Cron':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_Integration':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_CustomerGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_Deploy':    
Module 'Magento_Developer':    
Module 'Magento_Dhl':    
Module 'Magento_AsynchronousOperations':    
Module 'Magento_DirectoryGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Running schema recurring...    
Module 'Magento_BundleGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':    
Module 'Magento_AdvancedSearch'    
Module 'Magento_Email':    
Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':    
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':    
Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':    
Module 'Magento_Ui':    
Module 'Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl':
Module 'Magento_PageCache':    
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':    
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_GroupedCatalogInventory':    
Module 'Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_AuthorizenetAcceptjs':    
Module 'Magento_InstantPurchase':    
Module 'Magento_Analytics':    
Module 'Magento_Inventory':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryBundleProduct':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalog':    
Module 'Magento_InventorySales':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfiguration':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection':
Module 'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryElasticsearch':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryExportStockApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryIndexer':    
Module 'Magento_InventorySalesApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryCache':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification:    
Module 'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryProductAlert':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryReservations':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryReservationCli':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryReservationsApi':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryExportStock':    
Module 'Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi':
Module 'Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator':

Module 'Magento_InventoryShipping':

Module 'Magento_Shipping':    
Module 'Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi':

Module 'Magento_InventorySourceSelection':

Module 'Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi':    
Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':    
Module 'Magento_Marketplace':    
Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_MessageQueue':    
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct':    
Module 'Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':    
Module 'Magento_MysqlMq':
Running schema recurring...    
Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':    
Module 'Magento_Newsletter':    
Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':    
Module 'Magento_SalesRule':    
Module 'Magento_GraphQlCache':    
Module 'Magento_Vault':
Module 'Magento_Paypal':    
Module 'Magento_Captcha':    
Module 'Magento_PaypalCaptcha':

Module 'Magento_Persistent':    
Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Running schema recurring...    
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':    
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':    
Module 'Magento_QuoteAnalytics':    
Module 'Magento_QuoteGraphQl':
Module 'Magento_ReleaseNotification':    
Module 'Magento_Reports':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':    
Module 'Magento_Review':    
Module 'Magento_ReviewAnalytics':    
Module 'Magento_Robots':    
Module 'Magento_Rss':    
Module 'Magento_Elasticsearch':    
Module 'MSP_ReCaptcha':    
Module 'Magento_SalesAnalytics':    
Module 'Magento_SalesGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':    
Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':    
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':    
Module 'Magento_Elasticsearch6':    
Module 'Magento_CustomerAnalytics':    
Module 'Magento_SendFriend':    
Module 'Magento_SendFriendGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi':    
Module 'Magento_Signifyd':    
Module 'Magento_Sitemap':    
Module 'Magento_InventoryGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_Webapi':    
Module 'Magento_SwaggerWebapi':    
Module 'Magento_SwaggerWebapiAsync':    
Module 'Magento_Swatches':    
Module 'Magento_SwatchesGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':    
Module 'Magento_Tax':    
Module 'Magento_TaxGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':    
Module 'Magento_DownloadableGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_ThemeGraphQl':    
Module 'Magento_Tinymce3':    
Module 'Magento_Translation':    
Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':    
Module 'Magento_Ups':    
Module 'Magento_SampleData':
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_CatalogAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Usps':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':

Module 'Magento_Braintree':

Module 'Magento_VaultGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_WebapiAsync':

Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':

Module 'Magento_Weee':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_WeeeGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_WishlistAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_WishlistGraphQl':

Module 'Amazon_Core':

Module 'Amazon_Login':

Module 'Amazon_Payment':

Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Klarna_Core':

Module 'Klarna_Ordermanagement':

Module 'Klarna_Kp':

Module 'Magento_PaypalReCaptcha':

Module 'MSP_TwoFactorAuth':

Module 'Temando_Shipping':

Module 'Vertex_Tax':


Installing user configuration...

Enabling caches:
Current status:
Array
(
[config] => 1
[layout] => 1
[block_html] => 1
[collections] => 1
[reflection] => 1
[db_ddl] => 1
[compiled_config] => 1
[eav] => 1
[customer_notification] => 1
[config_integration] => 1
[config_integration_api] => 1
[full_page] => 1
[config_webservice] => 1
[translate] => 1
[vertex] => 1
)


Installing data...
Data install/update:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Amqp':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_Security':

Module 'Magento_GraphQl':

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_StoreGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_Widget':

Module 'Magento_Quote':

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':

Module 'Magento_Payment':

Module 'Magento_CmsGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_User':

Module 'Magento_Sales':

Module 'Magento_Checkout':

Module 'Magento_EavGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_Integration':

Module 'Magento_CustomerGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':

Module 'Magento_AsynchronousOperations':

Module 'Magento_DirectoryGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':

Module 'Magento_CatalogGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Bundle':

Module 'Magento_BundleGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedSearch':

Module 'Magento_Email':

Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':

Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Ui':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GroupedCatalogInventory':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_AuthorizenetAcceptjs':

Module 'Magento_InstantPurchase':

Module 'Magento_Analytics':

Module 'Magento_Inventory':

Module 'Magento_InventoryAdminUi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryApi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryBundleProduct':

Module 'Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalog':

Module 'Magento_InventorySales':

Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogApi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch':

Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct':

Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer':

Module 'Magento_InventoryConfiguration':

Module 'Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection':

Module 'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryElasticsearch':

Module 'Magento_InventoryExportStockApi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryIndexer':

Module 'Magento_InventorySalesApi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer':

Module 'Magento_InventoryImportExport':

Module 'Magento_InventoryCache':

Module 'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification':

Module 'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryProductAlert':

Module 'Magento_InventoryReservations':

Module 'Magento_InventoryReservationCli':

Module 'Magento_InventoryReservationsApi':

Module 'Magento_InventoryExportStock':

Module 'Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi':

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi':

Module 'Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator':

Module 'Magento_InventoryShipping':

Module 'Magento_Shipping':

Module 'Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi':

Module 'Magento_InventorySourceSelection':

Module 'Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi':

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_MessageQueue':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct':

Module 'Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_MysqlMq':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':

Module 'Magento_Newsletter':

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':

Module 'Magento_GraphQlCache':

Module 'Magento_Vault':

Module 'Magento_Paypal':

Module 'Magento_Captcha':

Module 'Magento_PaypalCaptcha':

Module 'Magento_Persistent':

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':

Module 'Magento_QuoteAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_QuoteGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_ReleaseNotification':

Module 'Magento_Reports':

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_Review':

Module 'Magento_ReviewAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Robots':

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_Elasticsearch':

Module 'MSP_ReCaptcha':
Upgrading data...

Module 'Magento_SalesAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_SalesGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Elasticsearch6':

Module 'Magento_CustomerAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_SendFriend':

Module 'Magento_SendFriendGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi':

Module 'Magento_Signifyd':

Module 'Magento_Sitemap':

Module 'Magento_InventoryGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_SwaggerWebapi':

Module 'Magento_SwaggerWebapiAsync':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':

Module 'Magento_SwatchesGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Tax':

Module 'Magento_TaxGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_ThemeGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_Tinymce3':

Module 'Magento_Translation':

Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':

Module 'Magento_Ups':

Module 'Magento_SampleData':

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_CatalogAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Usps':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':

Module 'Magento_Braintree':

Module 'Magento_VaultGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_WebapiAsync':

Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':

Module 'Magento_Weee':

Module 'Magento_WeeeGraphQl':

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':

Module 'Magento_WishlistAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_WishlistGraphQl':

Module 'Amazon_Core':
Upgrading data...

Module 'Amazon_Login':

Module 'Amazon_Payment':
Upgrading data...

Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
Installing data... Upgrading data...

Module 'Klarna_Core':
Upgrading data...

Module 'Klarna_Ordermanagement':

Module 'Klarna_Kp':
Upgrading data...

Module 'Magento_PaypalReCaptcha':

Module 'MSP_TwoFactorAuth':
Installing data... Upgrading data...

Module 'Temando_Shipping':
Upgrading data...

Module 'Vertex_Tax':
Installing data... Upgrading data...

Data post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Amqp':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_Theme':
Running data recurring...

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Customer':
Running data recurring...
```

Comment: Can you check var/log/ im Magento directory and apache2 error log

Comment: @BartZalas . apache2 error log is :- [Thu Jan 30 04:04:15.395063 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2236:tid 140026434071488] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: @BartZalas and magento error log is :- [2020-01-30 09:52:18] main.ERROR: Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] []

Comment: It's looks like it stop on setup:update. Just run setup:update and switch to developer mode , clean cache and check is it working.

Answer (score 0):

yeah If you spend a lot time then turn off computer and go out a while

Comment: BTW that setup is running on ubuntu EC2 instance and tried many time doing restart the instance.